# Why does the declared type of an object matter at runtime?

Tags: java, oop, types

In a statically-typed language like Java, from what I've learned, type declaration is essentially for compile-time catching of errors, an obvious advantage over dynamically typed languages. But looking at the times when Java does late binding, we get errors like `ClassCastException`, showing how the declared types are relevant somehow at runtime. But why does the declared type actually matter?

For example:

```
public class TestClass 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       Animal d = new Animal();
      ((Dog)d).bark(); //ClassCastException because an Animal is not a dog, which would make sense to throw at compile-time, but not at runtime.
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal{}

class Animal
{
   void bark()
   {
       System.out.println("Woof");
   }
}
```

I know this is a super bad example because it's an unnessesary cast, but I'm just giving an example of it. We try to avoid runtime exceptions at all times, so why can't Java disregard the cast and call method `bark` on the actual object type, which in this case is `Animal`? I've been reading about duck typing and it seems like a similar adaption of this could work in Java (i.e. if this object woofs, then let's treat it like a dog!) or any statically-typed language, because at runtime, Java seems to act dynamically.

Edit: Now that I'm thinking about it more, this question is about the need for runtime type checking. Why does it need to happen? It seems bad that static typed languages halt with a runtime exception on a cast which could be ignored.

Comment: you don't need a cast in this case, since `bark()` is defined in `Animal`

Comment: @Ramanifc, I know, I couldn't think of a good example - my question is if I were to encounter a class cast exception like this, runtime won't proceed, but I'm wondering why it doesn't - is it a reliability issue or more general?

Comment: This behavior is probably related to the operator precedence. `()` has highest precedence so it's evaluated first and dot can not be evaluated first. You're right Java could decide to call the method if cast fails but what will happen to it's promise of well defined operator precedence ? Since it's following a publicly declared specification, it can not do things randomly.

Comment: You are referring to disregarding an *explicit* cast, yeah?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yep - I don't get why the declared type at runtime would even matter - polymorphism and the method acts on the actual object type so why does the invalid cast even matter at runtime? It makes sense at compile-time because Java doesn't know the actual type.

Comment: @11thdimension - you have a good point. The whole idea of runtime type checking and why the reference types of objects at runtime are even important are really unclear to me.

Comment: Runtime type checking is like server side input validation. Just in case some one tries to bypass the compile time validation (client side input validation), we still have runtime validation (server side rules) to thwart such attacks. This becomes more important in case of Java as it provides API's like reflection which can manipulate and load classes in runtime, where compiler doesn't come in picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course duck typing *could* work in Java. A lot of things could work in Java, but this is the way it's designed. The declared type matters exactly because Java is statically typed and not something else.

Static typing is not compile time only. Certainly a big portion of it is to verify that the code can run correctly. But it's not enough. Since it's not always possible to verify that the types are always correct (such as casting an `Object` parameter to a specific class), there needs to be runtime type checking as well. If it were `static` at compile time and `duck` at runtime, it could create **very** confusing and hard to debug situations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my understanding of static typing is for compile-time detection only, not for catching at runtime. After all, Java looks at the actual type of the object when encountering late binding situations, so why do static typed languages still stick to these rules post compile time?

Comment: this is helpful, thank you. Can you explain why runtime type checking has to happen in a static-typed language? I think answering that will actually answer my question.

Comment: There's a great explanation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type-checking). As you see there's more than one way to skin a cat, but it pretty much always involves (at least some form of) type checking at runtime.

Comment: That's a good explanation - thanks. "Therefore, a dynamic check is needed to verify that the operation is safe" - okay, so here, we're doing a downcast which is unsafe but not impossible like calling a string method on an integer object. But it's fatal. That doesn't make sense. The only reason why it makes sense to me for it to fail at compile-time is because Java only knows reference types, but at runtime, Java knows the actual types.

Comment: Well in "normal" code Java will give you a compile-time error (such as if you were to write in the above code `Dog dog = d;`). However here you're forcing the type system with a cast. In this case it's obvious that an `Animal` is not a `Dog`, but it's not worth it to spend a lot of time on the static type checking. If the programmer says that all `Animals` are `Dogs`, fine. It'll blow up eventually anyway.

Comment: right, but it doesn't blow up in my example because `((Dog)d).bark();` should work just fine ignoring the cast.

Comment: But we're not ignoring the cast. You're attempting to make an illegal cast, which is an error (at least as far as Java is concerned).

Comment: you're right, and at compile-time this type of illegal cast makes sense to be an error because if treating an `Animal` like a `Dog`, you should be able to call `Dog` methods on the `Animal`, which the compiler couldn't catch if you attempted to do because it only knows of the reference type. But here, Java uses information about the real object type, so I don't even see why casts would even make a difference or be illegal at the point of runtime. I've always learned casting and declaration of type is just for the sake compile-time type checking.

Comment: Well then you've learned wrong. A wrong cast is an error. You can come up with imaginary situations and theories about how something **could** work differently, but you're wasting your time. You can use a cast to bypass static checking, but you can't bypass the runtime type check. At the runtime type check a cast to a wrong class is an error, no matter how you feel about it.

Comment: It would help a ton if I could see an instance of when the declared type or cast actually matters at runtime rather than at compile-time, besides in the case of virtual/non-virtual methods, which rarely is encountered in Java.

Comment: It's hard to come up with an example, because you think that Java should have duck typing and it shouldn't matter what kind of crazy casts you do at runtime, just as long as the method is there.

Comment: and you're right that having `duck` at runtime and `static` at compile-time would be chaos, so if the actual reason why duck typing isn't an option is because of this consistency, then I'm satisfied. Thanks for your help @Kayaman - I know this was an extended discussion.

Answer (score 5):

> why can't Java disregard the cast and call method bark on the actual
>   object type, which in this case is Animal?

That would be semantically wrong thing to do. What if `Dog` and `Amimal` has different versions of `Bark` method?

Let's say you have a non virtual method `Bark` in your base class. When you call `Bark` on `Dog` it should call `Dog.Bark`; similarly when you call `Bark` on `Animal` it should call `Animal.Bark`.

If the compiler disregards the cast as you said, it would end up calling the wrong method.

Note that in C# by default all methods are non virtual as opposed to java. So this argument makes more sense in the context of C#.

Comment: But with polymorphism, it'll always call the actual type at runtime, no?

Comment: @rb612 Yes but I talked about non virtual methods. Did you missed it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel But **all** methods in Java are virtual. Methods are always dispatched to the runtime type.

Comment: @resueman Well, there can be `final` methods right? Does that count as a non virtual method? If not, consider my answer is about `c#` as the question is tagged c#.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you're right - I missed that part. I see what you mean now. That's a good argument. I'm trying to see a Java equivalent where it's more polymorphic.

Comment: However in case of cast exception, Java Runtime already knows that Dog is not a compatible type with Animal.

Answer (score 1):

`Can you explain why runtime type checking has to happen in a static-typed language`

Yes, here are a few reasons

1. Compiled class Dog was replaced by someone, from other project and new class doesn't even extend Animal.
2. Compiled class Dog is loaded via Dserialization and some wrong version of of Dog was packed.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.com.example.Animal cannot be cast to com.example.com.example.Dog
>       at com.example.com.example.Test.main(Test.java:12)

As you can see error,
The compiler fails to detect the type casting error, because down casting "((Dog)d)" is a valid casting if the reference Dog is a Animal  object. so it throw runtime error instead compile time.

Comment: Thanks @bmt - this is a bad example I gave but I'm asking about the behavior of `ClassCastException` in general.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know which actual object being referenced. It only knows the reference type. The actual object comes into picture at runtime. So, the compiler wouldn't  give you compiler error for that.

Comment: Correct, I know that it'll throw a `ClassCastException`, which is at runtime, and not catch the compile-time error. That's what my question is about - runtime, not compile-time.